# short cut for itemize of latex

Tags: beamer

I realize that I've used the following format a lot in preparing for a lecture I'm currently teaching.

```
\begin{itemize}
\item<1-> ******
\item<2-> ******
\item<3-> ******
\end{itemize}
```

Was wondering, is there any shortcut for this?
Many thanks for your time and attention. Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need mark down like syntax?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you mean a shortcut for an editor or? Can you please explain better what your problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid putting the overlay instruction for each item by using:

```
\begin{itemize}[<+->]
\item ******
\item ******
\item ******
\end{itemize}
```